# SCCM 2007: Distribution point update schedule for Software Updates package

Tags: sccm, sccm-2007

If you create a package in Software Distribution, you can create a recurring distribution point update schedule under the "Data Source" tab.  However, this option does not appear to exist for packages in Software Updates.  Can the schedule be controlled for Software Updates packages?  If not, what is the hard-coded update schedule?  Can we disable automatic updating of the packages if we cannot control the schedule?  Some of our technicians do not click to update the distribution points at night after approving updates, and it is automatically rolling the updates out the next morning.  All of the data going out is killing our connections, and we are unable to distribute any QoS configurations as a result of political arguments over what packets will take precedence.  Yes, seriously.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We converted our remote sites to branch distribution points.  This is the sort of scenario that BDPs are really intended for: remote sites with limited bandwidth.  The branches update from a standard distribution point by using BITS.  We can set BITS to throttle during business hours and then allow free roam after hours.